# Explicit Call to a Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I know the concept that we can call the Constructor both `Explicitly` and `Implicitly`, and i have tested both the scenarios(generally till now my all purposes got fulfilled by calling constructor `Implicitly`), but i was wondering that constructor get called implicitly whenever we create `objects`, so what is the main reason behind calling the constructor `Explicitly`. What advantage or disadvantage it provides when we call constructor `Explicitly` over the `Implicit Call`?

Example

```
class integer
{
   int m ,n;
 public:
   integer (int x , int y); 
};
integer :: integer (int x , int y )
{
   m=x; n = y;
}
```

Now if i call like

```
integer int1 = integer( 0 , 100); //  Explicit Call
integer int1(1,100); // implicit call
```

Comment: For one thing, a constructor with two or more arguments can *only* be called explicitly.

Comment: Can you show some code that only uses implicit constructors? I feel like there's some context missing from the question.

Comment: Well, your example entitled *"Explicit call"* is actually an explicit call to the two-argument constructor followed by an implicit call to the copy-constructor, whereas your example entitled *"Implicit call"* is actually an explicit call. So you should first order your definitions before asking about any advantages, because not everything that can be done by an explicit constructor call can be done by an implicit one (as *aschepler* already noted), which would be a definite advantage.

Comment: @Christian Rau my code is just a sample code to show every call ,,,i just want to ask taht i can call constructor by both types but why to use EXPLICIT CALL

Comment: @Tejendra Ok, letting aside the real definition of explicit call and considering your own, then choosing `integer int1 = integer(0, 100)` over `integer int1(1, 100)` indeed makes no sense here. But keep in mind that the actual definition of an explicit constructor call is something completely different (and your second example is actually an explicit constructor call), which makes most of the existing answer not answering your actual question at all. And which gives explicit constructor calls a whole bunch of advantages, as you use them most of the time for things you cannot do with implicits.

Comment: @Christian Rau ...ok so according to ur statment `And which gives explicit constructor calls a whole bunch of advantages, as you use them most of the time for things you cannot do with implicits.` can you please write down those advantages in form of an answer.?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two different problems here, as your definition of *explicit* and *implicit* does not match the standard definition (on which most of the existing answers are based, being written before you added your example containing your own definition of *explicit* and *implicit*).

Ok so let's first consider your definition of *explicit*, which would be (I guess you call it *explicit* because you explicitly write the type name?):

```
integer int1 = integer(0, 100);
```

versus your definition of *implicit* which would be:

```
integer int1(1, 100);
```

In this case the first *"explicit"* call really doesn't have any advantage over the second *"implicit"* call. But there is still a difference. The first one actually creates a temporary using the two-argument constructor, which is then used to create `int1` using the copy constructor. Although in practice the compiler will usually optimize away this additional copy, it still won't work if your copy constructor is private, whereas the second one only needs the two-argument constructor (you could even see this as disadvantage).

---

But now to the actual standard definitions of *explicit* and *implicit*. An *explicit* constructor call is any constructor call you, well, explicitly call. Practically speaking, whenever you use the parenthesis syntax `()` to create an object you explicitly call a constructor, otherwise it's an *implicit* constructor call (so to say, being done behind the scenes by the compiler):

```
integer int1;                   // implicit default constructor
integer int1(1, 100);           // explicit two-arg constructor
integer int1 = integer(0, 100); // explicit two-arg constructor, implicit copy constructor

void func(integer);             // function taking by-value
func(int1);                     // implicit copy constructor
```

So the only constructors that can be called *implicitly* are the default construtor and any one-argument constructors (including copy and move constructors). A special problem in this regard are one-argument constructors not being copy/move constructors:

```
struct integer
{
    integer(int);
};
```

This allows the compiler to *imlicitly* call the the constructor to convert types, thus any `int` is implicitly convertible to `integer`:

```
void func(integer);
func(42);             // implicit call to int-constructor
```

To disallow such behaviour you would have to mark the constructor `explicit`:

```
struct integer
{
    explicit integer(int);
};
```

Which only allows it to be called *explicitly* (e.g. `func(integer(42))`) (but I guess you already knew this). This has the advantage that it doesn't introduce unnoticed/unwanted conversions behind the scenes, which can lead to all kinds of hard to find problems and ambiguities regarding overload resolution. It is therefore usual practice to mark any conversion constructors (one-argument non-copy/move constructors) `explicit`, and most probably also the reason why C++11 finally introduced `explicit` conversion operators.

---

So to sum up, according to your definition and example, there is really no advantage in using `integer int1 = integer(1, 100);` instead of `integer int1(1, 100);`, though it makes a (usually irrelevant) difference.

But according to the standard definitions, *explicit* constructor calls have plenty advantages over *implicit* ones, since the only way to actually construct an object **explicitly** is to use a, well, *explicit constructor call*, whereas *implicit constructor calls* are only done behind the scenes in certain situations and only work for zero- and one-argument constructors (as *aschepler* already pointed out). And explicitly marking conversion constructors as `explicit` has the advantage of disallowing unwanted implicit conversions behind the scenes.

Comment: i guess it solves my problem to an extent.. i had the idea about advantages of Explicit constructor( by appending the name of constructor with explicit key word ) btw thnx for the elaboration.

Comment: ..but i dint get ur one point behind the line `mplicit constructor calls are only done behind the scenes in certain situations and only work for one-argument constructors(for zero argument i get it`...please edit ur anser with this too

Comment: @Tejendra I added a discussion of the advantage of explicitly (pun intended) marking constructors `explicit`.

Comment: @Tejendra I don't know what else to say. Whenever you write `(...)` for creating an object this is regarded an *explicit* constructor call by the standard definition of the word *explicit* (and contrary to the definition used in your example code). The only time when a constructor call is called/named/regarded `implicit` by the standard definitions is, when it it is done behind the scenes by the compiler, without you **explicitly** creating a new object. So `integer int1(whatever);` is always called an `explicit constructor call`, contrary to your own definition.

Comment: @Tejendra For example the compiler can (and will) implicitly copy an object (using the copy constructor) when passing it to a function by-value or returning it from a function. Or it can implicitly convert an object of one type to an object of another type (using the corresponding constructor, if it isn't marked `explicit`). Those are all one-argument constructors.

Comment: @Tejendra It cannot use two-(or more)argument constructors implicitly, since well, there is no way to represent two values that should be converted into one (using some constructor). How would you e.g. call `void func(integer)` to make the `(int,int)`-constructor be called implicitly? You cannot just call it `func(1, 100)`, you can only (implicitly) convert **one** object of some type into **one** object of another type.

Answer (score 2):

Calling constructors **explicitly** allow you to construct object with arguments, rather than using the **default constructor**.

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo() {}
    Foo(int bar) : mBar(bar) {}
  private:
    int mBar;
}

Foo f;    // Implicitly constructed with default constructor.
Foo f(7); // Explicitly constructed with argument for 'bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways a constructor can be called:

- Implicitly, by declaring an instance of the type without initializing it
- Also implicitly, by either initializing an instance with `=` or by causing an implicit conversion from the argument type to your class.
- Explicitly calling the constructor, passing arguments.

Which of these you can use in a particular context depends on the constructors you're calling.

```
class Foo 
{
    Foo();                                  // 1
    Foo(int a);                             // 2
    explicit foo(const std::string& f);     // 3
    Foo(int c, int d);                      // 4
};
```

1. This constructor will be called implicitly when declaring `Foo f;`. **Never** attempt to call a constructor without arguments explicitly, as `Foo f();` will *declare a function!*
2. This one can be called by writing `Foo f = 42;` or `Foo f(42)`.
3. The `explicit` keyword forbids implicit conversion by writing `Foo f = std::string("abc");` or `function_taking_foo(function_returning_string());`.
4. As there are multiple arguments, the explicit version is the only suitable.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say this, because it is so perverse, but there is an additional way to explicitly call the constructor.

```
class integer
{
   int m ,n;
 public:
   integer (int x , int y); 
};
integer :: integer (int x , int y )
{
   m=x; n = y;
}
```

The constructor can be explicitly called on an already-constructed object.

```
integer i(1,100);
i.~integer();
i.integer::integer(2,200);
```

Here I've constructed (explicitly) an instance of integer. Then I've explicitly called its destructor. Then I've explicitly called the constructor again. I suppose you might use this idiom in testing. I am not aware of any place in the standard that forbids it. It works in Visual Studio 2010. I haven't tested a really wide range of compilers.

These calls are explicit for large values of 'explicit'.

Comment: I tried in g++ compiler but it gave this error.. ---> error: cannot call constructor 'integer::integer' directly

Comment: I don't think instance.Class::Class(...) is valid syntax, but you can still do it: `new (&i) integer(2,200)`. Also note that you don't need to call the destructor first; the C++ object model does *not* require destructors to be called. Though in practice the class itself might implicitly depend on it happening, so it's a good idea when it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a function that takes a reference to a object of your class, and you pass it another type other than your object the constructor of your class will convert that type to an object of your class. Any one argument constructor is treated as a conversion constructor. If you declare that constructor explicit, then passing a different type other than your object to that function will not convert it and the compiler will return an error